# Are generators of finite cyclic groups unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Are generators of finite cyclic groups unique?
Can someone explain to me why they are unique or why they are not?

Comment: By a ‘cyclic’ group, do you mean a *finite* cyclic group?

Comment: I believe so yes.

Comment: Even for the infinite cyclic groups we have more than one possibility for a generator. So generators of cyclic groups are never unique, except for the trivial group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Hint: consider $\mathbb Z_7$; you can check by hand that it has more than one generator.

It is also easy to check that for any $[m]$ relatively prime to $n$, $[m]$ generates $Z_n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the cyclic group of size $3$,
$$
C_3 = \{e, a, a^2\},
$$
where $a^3 = e$.

Which of the elements are generators? You can try all three of them. Is $e$ a generator? is $a$ a generator? And is $a^2$ a generator?

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a generator of the cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ (in multiplicative notation), every element of $G$ can be written in the form $g^k$, where $0\le k <o(g)$.

Furthermore, the order of such an element is
$$o(g^k)=\frac{o(g)}{\gcd(o(g),k)}=\frac n{\gcd(n,k)},$$
hence an element $g^k$ is a generator of $g$ if and only if $k$ is coprime to $n$. There are $\varphi(n)$ such elements.